# Drawing matches from Nearest Neighbour Distance Ratio

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection

In openCV I have adapted this tutorial code in my application

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography

I have been trying to prune the matches using the Nearest Neighbour Distance Ratio to only draw matches above a certain threshold value.

```
  double ratio = 0.9;
  std::vector< vector<DMatch > > nnMatches;
  std::vector< DMatch > good_NNmatches;
  matcher.knnMatch(descriptors_scene, descriptors_object, nnMatches, 2 );

  for(int k = 0; k < nnMatches.size(); k++)
  {
      if(nnMatches[k][0].distance / nnMatches[k][1].distance > ratio)
      {
          good_NNmatches.push_back(nnMatches[k][0]);
      }
  }
```

I am then trying to draw the matches in good_NNmatches using the same method demonstrated in the tutorial but I get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (i1 >= 0 && i1 < static_cast<int>(keypoints1.size())) in     drawMatches, file /Users/cgray/Downloads/opencv-2.4.6/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp, line 207
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/cgray/Downloads/opencv-2.4.6/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp:207: error: (-215) i1 >= 0 && i1 < static_cast<int>(keypoints1.size()) in function drawMatches
```

When trying to call drawMatches using good_nnMatches instead of good_matches as described in the tutorial.

```
drawMatches( roiImg, keypoints_object, compare, keypoints_scene,
                     good_NNmatches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
                     vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );
```

Comment: I don't know if that is the cause of your problem, but your conditionnal is wrong. You should add a match in `good_NNmatches` if `nnMatches[k][0].distance / nnMatches[k][1].distance < ratio`.

Comment: That didn't solve the assertion error but I have changed the condition now and found a fix to the issue, Thanks.

Comment: Why don't we remove The ASSERTION FROM DRAW.CPP??????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some trial and error I appear to have solved this issue now.

I have changed the drawMatches method to swap the "roiImg" and key points with "compare" and key points.

```
drawMatches(compare, keypoints_scene, roiImg, keypoints_object,
               good_NNmatches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
               vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );
```

This stopped the assertion error. But due to swapping the values around when it came to retrieving the key points I also had to make some changes. trainIdx and queryIdx have also been swapped to account for the previous changes made.

```
obj.push_back( keypoints_object[ good_NNmatches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
scene.push_back( keypoints_scene[ good_NNmatches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. In my case I was doing

```
cv::Mat output;
drawMatches( smallimg, keyptsSm, bigimg, keyptsBg, matchesBig2Small, output );
```

Where the matches `matchesBig2Small` were computed from `bigimg` to `smallimg`

```
std::vector<cv::DMatch> matchesBig2Small; 
//match from bigimg to smallimg
```

So the error you got is actually saying that it's looking for the keypoint index in `smallimg` that actually refers to the second image, which is bigger so you're exceeding the size of `smallimg`. So either change the call to `drawMatches` to:

```
drawMatches( bigimg, keyptsBg, smallimg, keyptsSm, matchesBig2Small, output );
```

Or change the way you're computing the matches to be from `smallimg` to `bigimg`, so instead of `matchesBig2Small` you'd have `matchesSmall2Big`, and then the call would be:

```
std::vector<cv::DMatch> matchesSmall2Big; 
//match from smallimg to bigimg
drawMatches( smallimg, keyptsSm, bigimg, keyptsBg, matchesSmall2Big, output );
```

Comment: Thanks, this was precisely my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it and i don not have anyproblems
I hope that this code can help you

```
double NNDR;

    for(int i=0;i<(int)ORB_ORB_matches.size(); i++){

        NNDR= ( ORB_ORB_matches[i][0].distance/ORB_ORB_matches[i][1].distance );

        if(NNDR <= 0.9){

            ORB_single_matches.push_back (ORB_ORB_matches[i][0]);

        }

    }
drawMatches( image_1, keypoints_1, image_2, keypoints_2, ORB_single_matches, img_matches,Scalar::all(-1),Scalar::all(-1),vector<char>(),`enter code here`          DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS|DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);
```